# Setting up dual Wifi on Raspberry 3b

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, pi-3b+

I have installed raspbian with RASPAP. I need my Raspberry PI to deliver 2 WiFi SSIDs:

1. Work, not DHCP, transmit the Ethernet on WiFi for workers.192.168.1.
2. Guest: with DHCP on another LAN. Deliver IP in 192.168.10.

The "guest" network and "work" network cannot communicate together. The guest network uses the Ethernet to reach the internet.

Is it possible just using the WiFi module incorporated on the Raspberry Pi? Or do I need a WiFi stick to create the guest network?

I have connected internet to my raspberry pi. And I want to share this connection with 2 SSID "Work" and Guest_wifi".

This is mine:

```
valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-G                    O } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P                    -device } <= 1,
           total <= 4, #channels <= 1
Device supports scan flush.
Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in sched scans.
Supported extended features:
        * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_PSK ]: 4-way handshake with PSK in statio                    n mode
        * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_1X ]: 4-way handshake with 802.1X in stat                    ion mode
```

Comment: I once use a USB Wifi stick with my Rpi3B+.  I found that I can either use the built in Wifi chip, or the USB Wifi stick.  It is NOT possible to use both at the same time.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with deliver. Do you want to have two access points/hotspots so that others can connect to the RasPi, or do you want to connect as client to a remote access point/hotspot, or any combination of it? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo I have an ethernet signal directly connected to the raspberry PI. So My Pi have internet. And i want to diffuse two SSID: WORK and Guest.

Comment: @Ingo look down

Comment: The update is exactly what I wrote in my answer, no different output. It is the setting of the WiFi chip on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ that you use. With it **you can not use** two SSID "Work" and Guest_wifi" for two client connections. Please understand the difference between a client connection and an access point. I'm still unsure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to have two client connections to two different remote hotspots, one access point for WORK and one access point for GUESTS. These are so called managed connections. On a Raspberry Pi you can look what interface combinations are possible with:

```
rpi ~$ iw list
--- snip ---
valid interface combinations:
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
       total <= 3, #channels <= 2
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
       total <= 4, #channels <= 1
--- snip ---
```

With `#{ managed } <= 1` you can see that only one managed connection is possible. You can only use one SSID to connect to one remote access point. If you want a second connection you have to use an additional USB/WiFi dongle.